# a base use of Objective-C's retainCount

Tags: objective-c, retaincount

We both know that the retain method will +1 retainCount, release will -1 retainCount, if retainCount == 0, the object dealloc.
But I meet a problem, the following code run have the ridiculous result

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Person : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger age;

@end

@implementation Person
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = @"name";
        self.age = 20;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
    [super dealloc];
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Person *per1 = [[Person alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"retainCount = %lu -- 1",[per1 retainCount]);
    [per1 release];
    [per1 retain];
    NSLog(@"retainCount = %lu -- 2",[per1 retainCount]);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
2014-01-11 21:56:23.887 blockTest[1287:303] retainCount = 1 -- 1
2014-01-11 21:56:23.889 blockTest[1287:303] dealloc
2014-01-11 21:56:23.889 blockTest[1287:303] retainCount = 2 -- 2
```

I don't use the ARC. Why I get this result?
Isn't the app should crash?

Comment: Please read this: http://whentouseretaincount.com

Comment: Once you release `per1` (and the count goes to zero), all bets are off.  It's an error to retain an object that you don't currently "own".

Answer (score 7):

What's happening here is that although the object has been deallocated, the memory where it's stored hasn't been overwritten yet, so the later calls still work because the data is temporarily still there.

The reason you get a `retainCount` of 2 at the end is that when you send `release` to an object with a `retainCount` of 1, they just `dealloc` the object straight away without bothering to decrement the internal count to zero.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't ever expect that this property returns any meaningful result.
It doesn't matter what you do, it's not your job.

See this for more information [whentouseretaincount.com](http://whentouseretaincount.com)

Comment: That website is about using it in production code. Using it for learning and debugging is fine.

Comment: @grahamparks It isn't really useful for learning beyond learning how useless it is.   The moment you add threads, run loops, calls into the system or (under ARC) turn on/off the optimizer, the absolute retain count loses all concrete meaning.

Answer (score 2):

Once an object is deallocated, you cannot send any further messages to that object. In your case, your object is deallocated once you send the `release` message to it. Sending any further messages, including `retain` and `retainCount`, is undefined behavior.

For example, on my system, the following code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Person *per1 = [[Person alloc] init];
    [per1 release];
    Person *per2 = [[Person alloc] init];
    per2.name = @"Something Else";
    [per1 retain];
    NSLog(@"per1.name = %@",per1.name);
    return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
per1.name = Something Else
```

More undefined behavior!

Comment: This is the more correct answer. While `retainCount` should never be used, the problem here is that the variable is used after being deallocated.

Comment: Note that you can turn on malloc scribbling to make the app crash on the over-release.  Or turn on zombies.